# Creating files in bash from user input and a while loop

Tags: bash, input, scripting

I am creating a script that will take user input for a file name, and number of files to be created.

The script will then create the number of files required, and use the name given but increment the file name by one each iteration.

So lets say I want 3 files, named boogey. The output in the home folder would be; boogey1.txt, boogey2.txt and boogey3.txt.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=1
echo -n "Enter the number of your files to create: [ENTER]: "
read file_number
var2=file_number
echo -n "Enter the name of your file: [ENTER]: "
read file_name
var3=file_name
while [ "$var1" -le $file_number]
do 
    cat $file_name.txt
    #var1=$(( var1+1 ))
done
```

Comment: It generally helps to say what, specifically, you are having problems with when you ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is almost working. You just need to:

1. uncomment that `var1` assignment line
2. add a space between `$file_number` and `]` on the while loop line
3. change `cat` to `touch` (or any of a number of other possibilities) since `cat` doesn't create files it read them.
4. Use `$file_name$var1.txt` in the `cat` (now `touch`) line to actually use the incremented index instead of the bare filename.

That being said this script could be dramatically improved. See below for an example.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Enter the number of your files to create: [ENTER]: ' file_number
read -p 'Enter the name of your file: [ENTER]: ' file_name

for ((i = 1; i < file_number; i++); do
    : > "$file_name$i.txt"
done
```